# Android,How to Block URL in any Browser Programmatically?

Tags: android, url, browser, block

i wanted to Block URLs access from Browser in Android 
How i can do this without creating custom or own browser.

Comment: Take if the url is equal or contains the url if you want block, he show a message of error ou something else

Comment: You want to control browser app ? Or You want to do this in your app . Question seems unclear . Please Edit it with proper details .

Comment: if anyone tries to access that url from chrome or any other browser from my device , he should not able to access that or redirect to my specific URL .... like URL blocker.

Comment: @Nilesh u got any update on this ? Were you able to achieve the results?

Comment: @bhanu i found way with routing DNS table.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the `AccessibilityService`

Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64481011/509681

Instead of opening a new browser tab, you could just display some blocking overlay UI.